# How to remove dict where certain key is None

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to delete a dictionary where certain key is `None`.

For example I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
my = [{"mydata": ""}, {"mydata": "hello"}]
```

What I did is:

```
for my_list in my:
    if my_list["mydata"] == "":
        my_list.clear()
```

But this gives:

```
[{}, {'mydata': 'hello'}]
```

I want that `{}` empty dictionary to be removed, How can I achieve it ?

My desired result format is :

```
{"my_data": "hello"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
my = [{"mydata":""},{"mydata":"hello"}]
my2=[x for x in my if x['mydata']!='']
print(my2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try list comprehension with `any` or `all` depending on your usecase.
In the example given by you if there is only one key in the `dict` then `all` and `any` won't make much difference.

```py
my = [{"mydata":""},{"mydata":"hello"}]

my_new = [i for i in my if any(i.values())] #[{'mydata': 'hello'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use List Comprehension

```
my = [{"mydata": ""}, {"mydata": "hello"}, {"mydata": "bye"}, {"mydata": ""}]

new_my = [{x: y} for i in my for x,y in i.items() if y != ""]
print(new_my)
```

```
[{'mydata': 'hello'}, {'mydata': 'bye'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `remove()` rather than `clear()`, and iterate over a copy of the list to avoid issues

```
for my_list in my[:]:
    if my_list["mydata"] == "":
        my.remove(my_list)
```